# Jogging: Tibialis anterior muscle tense up whenever I jog

Tags: jogging

[image]

Whenever I jog for 10 minutes, Tibialis anterior muscle start to tense up to the point where it hurts. It's preventing me from doing long distance jogging.

I am not sure why this is happening. I usually walk for 5 minutes before I jog, giving it a bit of warning. But it doesn't seem to help.

I am 6' and 165 lbs. My left knee joint is slightly weak, so I try to jog softly, but that actually accelerates the process of Tibialis tense-up.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Has anyone solved this problem before?

Image from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tibialis.png

Comment: That image is under a license (CC-BY-SA 3.0), please add the relevant information if you copy such an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the problem with my calf. I talked to a friend of mine who is physiotherapist and we found out that my muscle was too short because I never stretched it. So try stretching your tibalis and whenever you jog stretch it dynamically before. If it doesn't help see yourselve a physiotherapist which is normally the best option.

Comment: You have a point. I am not very flexible and I never stretch before jogging.

Comment: But don't overstretch this will lower the strength of a muscle, just a little dynamical stretching before and a static stretching afterwards.

Comment: I have the same problem, what kind of stretching do you do for this muscles? Before and after running.

Comment: Well just google it;) here's one possibility: http://walking.about.com/od/stretching/a/shinstretch.htm But to be honest I never really stretched this muscle.

Answer (score 0):

If you stretch and pain gone, congratulations.
By stretch, I would say less than 30 seconds before exercise, and 90 seconds plus after exercise.
Remember to stretch other muscles like Extensor digitorum longus, 
Gastrocnemius muscle, or any muscle nearby, muscle tight may cause other muscle pain.

If not, you may take foot pressure image, and some possible topics like : overlaping toe, and supination/pronation

look at my answer here : https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/29823/20338