# Calves hurt in the front (the tibialis anterior muscle) from walking fast?

Tags: strength

I often brisk walk for rapid reaching of destination, and my legs aren't in bad shape; I have always been a walker, do calf exercises, but the front part of the calf (as mentioned in title). Why would it hurt? I didn't know that muscle needs to be worked.

Does the tibialis anterior need exercise directly (isolated) to get stronger, or is the pain there from walking from another potential reason?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal. It happens when walking quickly because you're pushing off the ground harder, your tibialis anterior needs to work harder to slow that down and bring your ankle back into dorsiflexion, and it holds it in that position longer than when running. Unless you ramp up your speed-walking too suddenly, it should just balance out eventually.

Here's a small reference: http://exercise.lifetips.com/tip/48909/walking/racewalking/sore-shins.html

Answer (score 0):

I used to have that problem and it went away after two or three weeks of doing squats, just three sets of 12 reps without any weight.

Answer (score 0):

It is not normal because you only walk, not running fast or exercise.

Your calves may lack stretch, try some like following : 
http://www.drnickcampos.com/health-newsletter/Los%20Angeles%20Chiropractic--shin%20splints.jpg

Remember to stretch less than 30 seconds before exercise, or any long/fast walk, and 90 plus seconds everyday before sleep.

If that does not solve your problem, you may have same issue like me. 
Search on topics like : overlaping toe, and supination/pronation

or read my answer here : https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/29823/20338

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue when I was younger.
Walking "fast" caused my shins to cramp up. (I assume you mean the shins with the front part?)

If this is the case, you should consider taking a magnesium supplement. This did wonders for me and helps push out the lactic acid your muscles.
As soon as I started taking a small magnesium supplement for about a week the pain just went away.

For me this was mainly an issue with my shins but while running I did notice the same in my calves and the magnesium worked fine for this too.
You will not need to take this forever but once you build up enough of it you can cycle it when needed.